# cv2 problem, error

Tags: 20.04, python, pycharm

I have the next question! I have an issue with cv2, I did install it by:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

But when I trying to run the file it's showing:

```
import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I using Ubuntu 20.04, PyCharm.

Comment: Nah, it is showing the same error...

Comment: ```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2

```

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 : **1.** `$ pwd` → assume /home/[name]/ → **2.** `$ python3` → → **3.** `>>> import cv2` → No issues. .... But if you are inside the PyCharm IDE, I guess it's a matter of the right settings. Or it can be a bug in PyCharm.